# Why is this private float field becoming zero?

Tags: java

I have some peculiar behaviour which I'm struggling to explain to myself. A float field, called "textureScale", becomes zero.

That could be explained if some code was changing the value. However then I would expect to be able to cause a build failure, or at least a runtime exception, by setting it to a "private final float" - then whatever is changing the value will fail. But if I do that, the code doesn't fail at all - it works great!

Can anybody help me understand what is possible here - why might this float become zero unless I set it final? Is there a Java-ism which I am unfamiliar with here? Is the only explanation some obscurity in code elsewhere?

```
public class TexturedBox extends Box {
    // This field becomes 0.0?
    private float textureScale = 1.0f;

    public TexturedBox(Vector3f center, float x, float y, float z) {
        super(center, x, y, z);
    }

    @Override
    protected void duUpdateGeometryTextures() {
        FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(24);

        buf.clear();

        // All the values in these puts are "zero" - since textureScale is now zero?
        buf.put(textureScale * 2f * xExtent); buf.put(0);
        buf.put(0); buf.put(0);
        buf.put(0); buf.put(textureScale * 2f * yExtent);
        buf.put(textureScale * 2f * xExtent); buf.put(textureScale * 2f * yExtent);
        // ... and more puts just like that ...

        buf.flip();

        setBuffer(Type.TexCoord, 2, buf);

        System.out.println(textureScale);
        // ^ This outputs zero
        // ... unless I set textureScale to final - then everything works?!
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but *complete* program?

Comment: Can java native methods work like C in that the value can be changed when passed by reference? Looks like a graphics lib, lots of native code there.

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted leads me to believe that `textureScale` is becoming `0`.

Comment: Hi Jon, admittedly I should have done that first - I suppose I was expecting someone to say "Ah, that's because in Java you have to initialize floats manually..." or similar. I will see if I can reproduce in a complete program :)

Comment: Sotrios - thanks - this is a perfectly acceptable answer to my question!

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the method. Is it called from the super constructor? If so, the field is not initialized at that point. If you declare the field final, the compiler may replace the field access with a constant expression, which will make it work.

Comment: Arian - yes, it is! This is mostly like the answer. Paste this in as an answer if you'd like it accepted, pending me testing, of course... this is exactly the kind of knowledge I was hoping someone might share

Comment: This is the reason you shouldn't call protected methods from the constructor. It can lead to unexpected behavior (as we see here).

Comment: I suppose this is not `javax.swing.Box` ? Then you should mention which class library you are using (if it is one known to mankind)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the method. Is it called from the super constructor? If so, the field is not initialized at that point, because the super-constructor is called before the field initialization of the subclass.

If you declare the field final, the compiler may replace the field access with a constant expression, which will make it work

Comment: Yes, the protected method is called in a super constructor. This is the issue - thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

I expected that `duUpdateGeometryTextures()` is being called from your super class' constructor.  When you do this, you are access the subclass before it's constructor is completed and not all fields will be set.

In your case, non-final fields are set *after* super is called.  Final fields are effectively static fields and get initialised first.

Comment: You are right :) Thanks for taking the time to answer - although Arian got there first! Much appreciated!